# Product search by title using Admin REST API

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-api-node, shopify-api

I am trying to retrieve products, which have a certain keyword in their title.

It is possible to search by full title like this:

```
/admin/api/2019-10/products.json?title=Name of my product
```

But I want to use **wildcard/regex** expression? How can I retrieve products which have, let's say "red", in their title?

---

### Edit:

Example products:

- Red car
- Red book
- Brown table

**query:** `/admin/api/2019-10/products.json?title=Red`

**Expected result:** Red car and Red book

But it returns an **empty array**.

Comment: Sorry, it's not working since `2019-07`, I was testing it on `2019-04` so it was working for me then. I deleted the old answer, see the new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working since `2019-07` API version.

> Requests that pass a value for `title` will match only if the value is
>   the same as the complete title. Partial matches aren't supported.

Source: [2019-07 release notes](https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/versioning/release-notes/2019-07)

Seems the only way is using GraphQL. See the suggested solutions below:

- [GraphQL solution 1](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/API-issue-can-t-fetch-products-filtering-by-their-title/m-p/575186/highlight/true#M38566)
- [GraphQL solution 2](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Shopify-REST-Admin-API-2019-10-with-Filter-by-title-has-two/m-p/635108/highlight/true#M43085)